# Android emulator shuts down after it starts

Tags: android

Hi!

I have a problem getting my android emulator to work. After i run my android application project, the emulator starts, but instead of showing my application, it says the following : "Power off. Shutting down..." and then the screen goes black. I'm unable to launch my application or do anything in the emulator.

What might be the problem? My target SDK is 1.5, and the device i chose is Nexus One. Thank you

Comment: LogCat or Console errors?

Comment: did you ever figure out the problem? I'm having same issue.

Comment: I was having a lot of issue in creating virtual device but none of the answer helped at last after spending 12 hours on this issue i was tired and i thought of myself, let just checked the graphic card driver is it install or not and it was not i simply installed nvidia driver and the problem got resolved

Answer (score 0):

did it work before? 
did try to wipe user data? (avd-launch option)

//edit:
I think Fuad is wrong:
if you change the ramSize to 1024M or 1024MB, the virtual device's amount of RAM is just set to 256MB

Answer (score -1):

I had problem at first some thing like this for using android SDK...check this maybe helps you :

> (YourWindowsDrive)C:\Users\YourLoginName(mine is Fuad) \ .android\avd\App.avd(This App.avd is a folder the name what I have used for my avd)

then in folder U see "config.ini". open it and change "hw.ramSize=1024" (mine is 1024 and maybe yours is different) to :

> hw.ramSize=1024M

Comment: I said that never change your Number to 1024...I just took an example to tell add "M" at the end of RAM size...I meant this...not about size 1024